# How to Deserialize the given sample

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, silverlight-5.0, xml-deserialization

Please Note that this application uses Silverlight5:

I have xml like this:

```
<A>
  <B>
     <C>C1</C>
     <D>D1</D>  
  </B>
  <B>
     <E>E1</E>
     <F>F1<F1>
  </B> 
</A>
```

I just have problem in the Parent class which is "A". How will i manage the reptition of "B" ? And how i will access the data node(child nodes) inside the both B on deserializing ? Because i will have the object of A class  and with that object **how would i differnceiate  between the two "B" to acess "C1,D1,E1,F1" ?**

```
My try to do this is :
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "A")]
    public class Parameter
    {
        [XmlElement("B")] //But what to do for another "B"
        public B B { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is B class

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "B")]
    public class Parameter
    {
        [XmlElement("C")]
        public string Label { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("D")]
        public string Type  { get; set; }
    }
```

But what and how to do for E and F element? **And how to acess C1,D1 and E1 AND F1  on derrialization?**

EDIT after `Andy Jones`,Suppose I try to get the object of "A" class like this:

```
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A));
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlstring));//HerexmlString contains my xml given above
        A a = (A)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Now using the Object `"a"` i want to access C1, D1 and C2,D2 . **Then how to do that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to deal with this XML using Serialization because you have two different definitions for the B node.

The closest you'll be able to get is:

```
<A>
  <B>
     <C>C1</C>
     <D>D1</D>  
  </B>
  <B>
     <C>C2</C>
     <D>D2</D>
  </B> 
</A>
```

But first you'll need to sort out the C# classes. Firstly, you have two classes with the same name and an incorrect reference to "B".

Class A should look like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "A")]
public class ParameterA
{
    [XmlElement("B")]
    public ParameterB B { get; set; }
}
```

...and class "B" should look like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "B")]
public class ParameterB
{
    [XmlElement("C")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("D")]
    public string Type  { get; set; }
}
```

That will allow you to get XML that look like:

```
<A>
  <B>
     <C>C1</C>
     <D>D1</D>  
  </B>
</A>
```

Now for the repetition of "B". Modify ParamaterA to have a list of Bs:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "A")]
public class ParameterA
{
    [XmlElement("B")]
    public List<ParameterB> B { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to create the XML above.

When you deserialize the XML to the classes you will be able to access the elements of B like this:

```
var firstParameter = a.B[0];
var secondParameter = a.B[1];
```

`List<T>` allows you to access elements by index (just like an array).

You could also iterate over the values with `foreach`:

```
foreach(ParameterB b in a.B)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser you seems close to what i wanna know. I have still two questions , Thanks if you could answer them as well to clear the doubts.(1)Is it the only change i have to make the repetition of "B" and (2) How i will acess the  "C2" and "D2" using object ontained of B class say "b"(B b;) ?How will the repeated B will make us acess to C1,D1,C2,D2 ? could you please give tht piece of code for that (suppose xml is stored in "String xmlStringVarible;")Thanks a lot

Comment: When you deserialize into A you will be able to access the repetition of B using: A.B[0] and A.B[1].

Comment: I have edited to the question for you please see the last part to know what i want.

Comment: But it's not an array . Could you please write a reference code for me  making my edited part code as help in doing so ? wOULD REALLY BE A HELP ?

Answer (score 1):

Minor correction to the XML:

```
<F>F1<F1>
```

should be

```
<F>F1</F>
```

Beyond that, it looks like the class A should have a collection of B elements:

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> B { get; set; }
}
```

and your B class should have properties for C, D, E, and F:

```
public class B
{
    public string C  { get; set; }
    public string D  { get; set; }
    public string E  { get; set; }
    public string F  { get; set; }
}
```